# Start two never ending python scripts

Tags: python, linux, bash, unix

Is there a proper way to start two python scripts that will never end?

I have a Bash Script.. I just want it to start two python server applications on different ports. But obviously as I get to the first python command, it will loop forever

is there a way to kill these two python scripts when you kill the bash script?

```
    #!/bin/bash

python RunConstantly.py
python RunConstantly2.py
```

Maybe this would be better to do in python?

Comment: You could just append an `&` to the end of each line.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
python RunConstantly.py  &
python RunConstantly2.py &
trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT
wait
```

If both background process die or get killed, then the `wait` command ends and script will exit normally.

If you interrupt the bash script (i.e. with Ctrl C) then the trap will kill the background jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you somehow keep the bash script from exiting upon last line, it's better to name your scripts properly, and to use `nohup` with `&`.

```
nohup python Work1.RC1.py > RC1.log 2> RC1.err &
nohup python Work1.RC2.py > RC2.log 2> RC2.err &
```

When you need to kill the tasks, search for the name of the scripts in your running process list

```
ps aux | grep Work1
```

and then use the process ids your find to kill them

```
kill -10 pid
```

Or you can chain the commands if you know there is no collision of process name in your system (which is why naming scripts properly is important at the first step)

```
ps aux | grep Work1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I{} kill -10 {}
```